# How to enable Direct3D 9 debug output on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, direct3d

I'm trying to figure out a bug with a Direct3D 9 app on a Windows 10 system. I've tried installing the DirectX SDK and opening its control panel as on previous Windows versions to enable running Direct3D in debug mode, but the options to enable it are all greyed out (including while running it as Administrator):

[image: DirectX Control Panel]

Both the 32-bit and 64-bit DirectX Control Panel apps have all of these control greyed out.

I also tried manually changing the `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Direct3D\LoadDebugRuntime` to `1`, but that didn't seem to have any effect (i.e. still no D3D debug output in DebugView.)

**What is the correct way to enable Direct3D 9 debug output in Windows 10?**

Answer (score 4):

Legacy Direct3D 9 debugging is not supported on Windows 8.x, Windows 10, or Windows 11. The last OS that supported it was Windows 7.

The DirectX SDK itself is end-of-life. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-).

> For new projects, the recommendation is to use Direct3D 11 or Direct3D 12 and avoid using the legacy DirectX SDK for dependencies. See [Living Without D3DX](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/), [Legacy D3DX on NuGet](https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/), and [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2021-edition/).